# append input only to currently hoverd li

Tags: jquery, list, hover

I'm trying to show an input field inside the currently hovered upon ul.
This code kind of works:

```
$('ul').hover(function(){
  $(this).append('<div style="display: block;"><input type="text"> <button>Knapp></button></div>');
},
function () {
      $(this).find("input:last").fadeOut('fast');
      $(this).find("button:last").fadeOut('fast');
    }

);
```

But it shows an input field for all the parents as well :/

I tried to remove the divs from the parents with find

```
      $(this).parents().find("input:last").fadeOut('fast');
```

But of course that code also finds the one that's inside the currently hovered ul...

[image]

Comment: I think this is an issue with propagation. The UL's are nested within each other, therefore hovering over a UL within a UL will cause this to happen as well. You should try to do something like $('ul > li > ul') to do direct descendent selection, or, give it a unique clas  `$('ul.inner')`, or you could try `$('ul').hover(function(e){ e.stopPropagation()` but i still think the initial problem will occur.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy yo sup man! set it as answer good idea will + you! `:)`

Comment: @Tats_innit ahh my good man Tats, howdy bud. I don't think I'll make it an answer unless OP finds my thoughts helpful. I like to keep answers clean and only if I'm sure my answer will be the solution. This is too vague of a scenario for my liking.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Bruverno `:)` , I am well, thanks! Howz life? you are a good human and a Legend of a man! Cool, worth an Idea to share which you did in comment! My offer still stand.

Answer (score 0):

you are append to the ul so it will work on all ul so try to specyfy the ul on which you want to append

and simpler approach is add a `id` or `class` to the ul

```
$('#one').hover(function(){
  $(this).append('<div style="display: block;"><input type="text"> <button>Knapp></button></div>');
},
function () {
      $(this).find("input:last").fadeOut('fast');
      $(this).find("button:last").fadeOut('fast');
    }

);
```

Comment: I want this to work for all the different uls, not just one with a specific id.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen because

the the childrens of `ul` are the part of `ul` so `input` will appended to them

you can use a condition

like `hasClass` or like `ul>li`

Comment: I understand that it's because I'm hovering the parent as well, I just don't know how to only for example add a class to the very one I'm visually hovering.

Comment: @Alisso you can use a `span` tag for that

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your input I changed my approach somewhat and now it works well enough.

I added an input field at the end of ever ul.
Hide it with css
Make it so that only the currently hovered on has class active (remove class from parents & children) and only show divs that are direct children of ul with class active :)

```
$('ul').hover(function(){
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $(this).parents().removeClass('active');
      $(this).children().removeClass('active');
    }, function(){
      $(this).removeClass('active');
    });
```

HTML

```
<ul class="tasks tasks-20">
<div><input type="text"> <button>Add main task</button></div></ul>
</li>
<div><input type="text"> <button>Add goal</button></div></ul><ul class="goals"><h2>The public</h2>

<li><span>: :</span>Follow our journey
<ul class="tasks tasks-24">
<div><input type="text"> <button>Add main task</button></div></ul>
</li>
<div><input type="text"> <button>Add goal</button></div></ul>
```

CSS

```
 ul.active>div{
            display: block;
    }
```